# What is the standard metric used in recommendation systems to evaluate the rankings?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, recommender-system, precision-recall, information-retrieval

I was searching for a metric to do this for a while and still could not find.
More specifically, my problem is as follows.

I have a ranked golden corpus. For example, consider that it looks as follows.

```
name, rank
n1   , 1
n2   , 2
n3   , 3 
n4   , 4
n5  , 5
and so on
```

Suppose, I have the top 5 results of two recommendation methods as follows.

```
model1 = [n18, n12, e1, n19, n11]
model2 = [n1, n2, e1, n3, e3]
```

If we consider precision@5 of `model1` it is 0.8 (i.e. `e1` is the only wrong one and others are in the golden corpus). P@5 of `model2` is 0.6 (i.e. `e1,e3` are incorrect).

However, if we look closely, `model2` outperforms as it tend to have the highly ranked elements in the golden corpus as its top recommendations compared to `model1`.

I looked for measures such as precision@k, mean average preciosn@k and none of them seem to support the point that I try to validate.

Please let me know if there is a suitable way to solve this issue.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159657/metrics-for-evaluating-ranking-algorithms

Comment: @Tim this is very helpful. I think NDCG suits my task. thank you :)